# PHP: Session files contain no data

Tags: php, file, session, cookies, session-variables

I've looked around on the internet, including stack overflow, for a few days trying to resolve my issue with PHP sessions. For one, I've noticed that most of the tutorials simply say "Here's the code, go use it." and not so much "This is how it works." Additionally, all of the issues/answers I find seem to be about information being lost on refresh or after switching pages and none of these apply to me.

The data in $_SESSION is being stored/loaded no matter which page I view. My issue is, when I view the session files on the server, there is no data in them. Additionally, when I destroy a session or unset the variables the information is still stored and the next time $_SESSION is accessed the old information is retrieved.

To troubleshoot the behavior of sessions on my server I created an extremely simple script:

```
<?php
// Use $HTTP_SESSION_VARS with PHP 4.0.6 or less
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}

echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
```

This is ALL of the code on the page (viewable here:  ). Every time this page is refreshed a new, blank, session file is saved into the specified directory on the server and the counter does not increase.

More information:
For information regarding php install: 
Hosted on GoDaddy Shared Hosting - Linux OS
I will update the permissions on the phpsessions directory to be temporarily browseable shortly. ()

Comment: A few of you have left notes on calling session_start(). I would like to emphasize that I posted a link to the phpinfo.php on my site ( gnerb.com/phpinfo.php ) in which it shows that session.auto_start is enabled and as such calling session_start() is not required. – everything 0 secs ago edit

Comment: Additionally, using javascript:alert(document.cookie); returns the session ID assigned to your session. The issue is, that even though a session cookie is sent to the viewers browser, the server is starting a new session every time the page is refreshed.

Comment: One more comment: I have made the phpsessions directory browse able temporarily so you can see the session files. To duplicate the issue, visit http://www.gnerb.com/count.php in one tab and http://www.gnerb.com/phpsessions in another tab. Refresh the count page and than refresh the directory listing and repeat. Each refresh creates / saves a session file instead of loading the session associated with the session ID given to the viewer upon the first visit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
I haven't been to stack overflow in a while and decided to look back at this question because it was 1 of the only 2 I asked. I'd like to mention that the issue was that the php session name was changed and needed to be changed back to the default.

Answer (score 3):

You need to call [`session_start()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before you try to use the session.

Answer (score 2):

You have to start your session using `session_start()`

**Not only once** in **every page** you use sessions make sure to have `session_start()`

Like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

// Use $HTTP_SESSION_VARS with PHP 4.0.6 or less
if (!isset($_SESSION['count'])) {
  $_SESSION['count'] = 0;
} else {
  $_SESSION['count']++;
}

echo $_SESSION['count'];
?>
```

Comment: Against my better judgement, I made the change you recommended and the session_start() function does not resolve the issue. Please refer to my comments on the original post.